# Better way to save and load Linear model coefficients for prediction

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict, rda, bigdata

I am working to make hourly coefficients for 50000 customers from one year data set. (365 rows*28 columns)

I want to save these coefficients for prediction later in another R code file. 
Currently, I am saving a list of 24 hourly models using save function for a customer. So, 50000 Rda files(7mb each). Then,loading (load function) them individually to predict using the predict function in R.

This is not efficient and now i want to do this for a million customers which will take lot of time and space.
Is there a better way to save coefficients from lm models to use for prediction later?

I tried biglm package but it doesn't save much space on the Rda files.
Also, manually multiplying the rows after saving the coefficients will be difficult as i have lot of variables with different factor levels.

Thanks!

Comment: Store your coefficients in a matrix format, then use matrix algebra to predict. `str(fit)` to see the large amount of extra fit related info that you probably don't need.

Comment: Related to @Vlo 's comment, check out this [blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2014/05/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/) about removing everything possible from a `glm` object while still being able to predict.

Comment: @vincentmajor Thank you for the advice. I was able to reduce my file size from 7mb to 10kb using the stripglm function given in the blog and the prediction remained unaffected. This should help me save space as well as reduce the processing time. The lm object sure does have a lot of junk in it when all you need is to predict with it.